# natural meaning of vector norms

Tags: normed-spaces, vectors

In class we learned how to calculate 1-norm, 2-norm, and infinity norm.  The instructor mentioned that each norm has a natural meaning in the context of a given problem. How can I tell which norm to use? For example, if each entry in a vector represents the number of people living in a house on my street, which norm will I use?

Comment: I think it depends on what information you are trying to extract from the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example

- the 1-norm can be interpreted as number of people living in the whole street
- the infinity-norm as number of people living in the house where the most people are living

Which norm you have to use will depend on the context.

But your example is a bit strange. For example you assume, that every street has the same amount of houses on it. And what is meant to be the sum of two streets?

Comment: In my example, that particular vector just represents the number of houses on my street.